# aware datetime field in def __unicode__ statement in model, and its representation in a template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I sometimes use model instances in templates.  For example, in the model below, I may use {{ leg }} which I would expect would display the information in the def **unicode**(self): section.  However, timezones complicate things.  Is there a way for my def **unicode**(self):  parameters to be timezone aware when a model instance is embedded in a template with a template tag?  Right now, it forces an aware unicode date representation of the string (which is my default timezone), but which doesn't make sense to the user.

```
class Leg(models.Model):
    startpoint = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    endpoint = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    drive_date_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Start date and time', blank=True, null=True)
    riders = models.ManyToManyField(Rider, blank=True)
    drivers = models.ManyToManyField(Driver, blank=True)
    carpool = models.ForeignKey(Carpool,  blank=True, null=True)
    open_to_prefs = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['drive_date_time']
        verbose_name = 'Drive leg'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  str(self.drive_date_time)  + ' | to: ' + self.endpoint
```

Comment: Have you checked out [new timezone support in 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones) ([and the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#support-for-time-zones))

Comment: Why are you using `str()` in `__unicode__()`?

Comment: I assumed I had to use str() when I wanted to combine the field with a string, in this case, the ' | to: ' + self.endpoint.  Is there a better way to do that?  I'm a beginner.  Thanks!

Comment: I've read the release notes and the documentation numerous times.  Unfortunately they don't describe what happens when you print a datetime or turn it into a string. It appears that it prints it out in the exact way it was stored in the db, regardless of what the current timezone is set as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you need to render a string of the text associated with a datetimefield, you can use the .astimezone() method associated with pytz.  This helps in a lot of situations, including the one above.